# Fineuploader - add jqCrop

Tags: javascript, jquery, fine-uploader

I already implemented drag&drop image sorting with Fineuploader (using jQuery Sortable for this), and now I would like to add jqCrop support (http://adriengibrat.github.io/jQuery-crop/). Ideally I would like to let the user crop the image before upload.

What would be the best way to implent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, I so no reason to use jqCrop.  It doesn't appear to do anything that [JCrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html) doesn't already do, and jCrop is much more widely used (and probably tested as a result).

With that in mind, here are the steps you must follow:

#### Step 1: Use JCrop to gather dimensions for the new image and then draw the desired section of the image onto a `<canvas>`.

You'll need to so the latter part of this yourself since JCrop doesn't actually seem to modify the image.  However, there's [a snippet of code that shows how this can be done](http://marx-tseng.appspot.com/image_crop/index.html).  The steps that the code follow are:

1. Grab dimensions of the crop from JCrop
2. Draw the image onto a `<canvas>`, ignoring everything outside of the cropped dimensions.
3. Grab a base64 representation of the `<canvas>` via a data URI.  You'll need this data URI for the next step.

#### Step 2: Turn the cropped version of the image into a `Blob`

Fine Uploader already does this for it's [image scaling feature](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/scaling.html) internally.  It seems reasonable to expose this via an API method in a future release (maybe even as part of the current or next release cycle), but, for now, you can just make use of [Fine Uploader's internal "private" function that does this on the prototype of the scaling module](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/blob/8eb2749c92d4510589150a2003620d8d1ff73fe1/client/js/scaling/scaler.js#L404).

Note - This code accesses a private function.  It may change, be renamed, or be removed at any time.  Please keep this in mind when you use this.  I will be sure to update this answer [once we make this all easier via an API method](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/1198) so direct access to this private method isn't necessary anymore:

`var croppedImageAsBlob = qq.Scaler.prototype._dataUriToBlob(data_uri_from_step1_above);`

#### Step 3: Submit the cropped `Blob` to Fine Uploader

The call in step 2 will return a `Blob`.  You can then pass this `Blob` to Fine Uploader via the [`addBlobs` API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#addBlobs) like this:

`uploader.addBlobs({blob: croppedImageAsBlob, name: "my cropped image.png"});`

Comment: Thanks, what I still  don't get is how to _replace_ the image in the queue with the cropped version. Ie., on file select, it get's loaded into canvas, cropped, and than the original file in the queue has to be replaced, right?

Comment: You can either issue a cancel API call for the original, or simply don't add the original to Fine Uploader.

Comment: @user1049961 Note that Fine Uploader will be adding a way to easily pass a canvas into the uploader via the API in the upcoming 5.1 release.  This means that you will not need step 2 or 3.    https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/1198

Comment: @ Ray Nicholus with changing the name  is possible

Answer (score 1):

**Clipping**

It seems that jqCrop doesn't really crop anything. If you want to let users crop their images **before** uploading, you have to edit images with javascript which can be done with Canvas.clip()

This library works pretty well: http://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/

**Uploading**

After image editing, you can get Base64 encoded image data from canvas then upload it to server:

Javascript:

```
canvas.toDataURL();
```

PHP:

```
$encodedData = str_replace(' ','+',$encodedData);
$decocedData = base64_decode($encodedData);
```

Comment: Thanks for great answer. When using the first method, how can I pass the cropped image into Fineuploader?

Comment: Fineuploader doesn't provide an option to upload through canvas. You may consider switch to https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Comment: I really tried hard to use blueimps FileUpload, but it was impossible to integrate with existing forms. I love FineUploader in this regard, and generally like FineUploader way more. But, this might be the case where it fails short...

Comment: It is trivial to pass an image represented on a canvas to fine Uploader.  Just convert the canvas to a blob and pass the blob to Fine Uploader's addBlobs API method.

Comment: I just found a method to use: http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/methods.html#addBlobs 
https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob

Comment: Yes, you can do this, but it's not required.  Fine Uploader converts canvas to blob internally for its scaling feature, and it does not use blueimp's library to do this.  We could easily expose that logic to make it even easier for users I suppose.

Comment: Thanks Ray. Can you give me some hints how to do this. I have autoUpload already set to false. So, I guess the user selects file, it should load into canvas, get cropped, and be passed back to Fineuploader to upload...

Comment: I only have access to my phone right now and it is tough to type anything long.  I'll provide an alternate answer sometime today that covers all this.  Stay tuned...

Comment: I've created an answer that should address your concerns.