# Implement JCrop in FineUploader

Tags: javascript, jquery, fine-uploader

I already made simple image uploading form using fine uploader, now I wanted to add image cropping feature using jcrop so user can resize their image before uploading the image but I'm really not sure where to start. I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23441589/fineuploader-add-jqcrop) thread but the link on step 1 of the accepted answer is broken, I'm still not familiar with HTML canvas so i really don't know where to start. can anyone help me how can I achieve this?

Comment: "the link on step 1 of the accepted answer is broken" You can also just follow the steps

Comment: archive at http://web.archive.org/web/20150305210412/http://marx-tseng.appspot.com/image_crop/index.html